# How to check for a value if it exists in another application - django

Tags: django

I have two applications in my django project, where I need to check and do some operations depending on whether a value exists in another application. I'm not sure how django does this. Any inputs or any links to django docs I can refer? Thanks.

Note: I do not want to get the value and use in my application. I just wanted if the value exists in another application.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean? Are you referring to another django app within the same project, or an entirely different project?

Comment: I'm referring to another django app in the same project!

Comment: Can you please show your code and explain what you are trying to check for, so I can help solve your problem?